# Multifile JavaScript sending wrong index order (also repeating index)

Tags: javascript, file, filereader, onload

I'm trying to send multiple files to dropbox using JavaScript and Ruby/Rails. First I have to decode an image with qr code and send it to my server in Ruby, then send it to dropbox. The problem is, when I'm trying to decode a file and send it, it is not going in the right order. I'm aware that this is probably because of the onload function of the reader. But how can I solve this and why this is the way it is?
PS: My qr code have to be a number (a code from the db), that's why I'm using 'isnum'
ps2: I tried 10 files and in my console.log that has 'j' have printed in this orded: 1, 7, 7, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, and 0. How can I make it to not repeat these indexes?

```
function setupReader(file, j){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        qrcode.decode(e.target.result);
        qrcode.callback = function(a){
            console.log("callback", j);
            var isnum = /^\d+$/.test(a);
            var form_data = new FormData();
            count_send++;

            if (isnum){
                form_data.append("code", a);
                form_data.append("file", file);
                // console.log(form_data);

                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                                request.open('POST', '/docs/baixaponto', /* async = */ false);
                request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                                request.send(form_data);

                                if (returnedStatus != 200){
                                    error_files_dropbox_baixa_filesimgs.push(e.target.result);
                                    e.target.result = "";
                                    error_files_dropbox_baixa_arquivos.push( returnedStringFinal );
                                    error_files_dropbox_baixa.push( file );
                                    error_files_dropbox_baixacount++;


                                }
                                else{
                                    success_files_filesimgs.push(e.target.result);
                                    e.target.result = "";
                                    success_files_arquivos.push( returnedStringFinal );
                                    success_files.push( file );
                                    success_filescount++;


                                }
            }
            else {
                error_files_decode_filesimgs.push(imgcoded64);
                e.target.result = "";
                error_files_decode.push( file );
                error_files_decodecount++;
            }
            if ( count_send == count ){
                 //function that opens a modal with file results
                 setTimeout(showdetalhedfiles, 2000);
            }
        };
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

The other function is:

```
function readqrcode(){
    f = document.getElementById('myfiles');
    count = f.files.length;

    if (f.files && f.files[0]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            setupReader(f.files[i], i);
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Nenhum arquivo selecionado");
    }
}
```

Comment: in the readqrcode() my first index was 1 and not 0. Thats weird

Comment: Because `reader.onload` is asynchronous, `j` is going to be whatever it was when the `onload` handler is run, not in any order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron for more information. You'll need to look into using a closure or object to get it to work. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Why do you need the dataURI for exactly?

Comment: @Kaiido to decode and find the qrcode

Comment: @HereticMonkey how/why is it going to work using object?

Comment: There are a number of ways of using an object to hold state while asynchronous code is running. I really encourage you to read the answers on that first link; they are all quite good at explaining asynchronicity and how to deal with it using the various technologies available to us.